# Connect custom cloudtrail with custom eventbus?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-event-bridge

Quick question. I was trying to create custom cloud-trail for one s3 bucket.
Create custom event bus in Eventbridge, so that I can map rules to this particular s3 events only.

Basiaclly I am trying to feed portion of my events related to particular s3 bucket to an event bus that can have seperate rules. But I think the only way is to set those rules in default eventbus? Like you cannot create a partial event bus (for particular groups of events) without a lambda in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your S3 events are preconfigured to be delivered to the default eventbus. If you want to send them to a custom bus, you can create a rule for cross-account event delivery.

There's additional documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eventbridge-cross-account-event-delivery.html